# Removing special characters from a dataframe column of phone numbers

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
Name    phone_number    status
john    8967894567      FC
john    8967894567      FC
john    7846897345      CL 
john    78.478954+89    FC
john    78.478954+89    FC
Ram     4598761458      FC
Ram     4598761458      FC
Kevin   15.478945+67    CL
```

I want to change it in order to have the following result:

```
Name    phone_number    status
john    8967894567      FC
john    8967894567      FC
john    7846897345      CL 
john    7847895489      FC
john    7847895489      FC
Ram     4598761458      FC
Ram     4598761458      FC
Kevin   1547894567      CL
```

I tried to use `re.sub` like this:

```
import re
df['phone_number'] = re.sub('[.+]', '', df['phone_number'])
```

but that resulted in this:

```
Name    phone_number             status
john    0  0 8967894567\n1  1547894567  FC
john    0  0 8967894567\n1  1547894567  FC
john    0  0 7846897345\n1  1547894567  CL 
john    0  0 7847895489\n1   1547894567  FC
john    0  0 7847895489\n1   1547894567  FC
Ram     0  0 4598761458\n1  1547894567  FC
Ram     0  0 4598761458\n1  1547894567  FC
Kevin   0  0 1547894567\n1  1547894567  CL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `re.sub`, it isn't suited to working with dataframes. Use `str.replace` in its stead.

```
df.phone_number = df.phone_number.str.replace('[^\d]+', '')
df

    Name phone_number status
0   john   8967894567     FC
1   john   8967894567     FC
2   john   7846897345     CL
3   john   7847895489     FC
4   john   7847895489     FC
5    Ram   4598761458     FC
6    Ram   4598761458     FC
7  Kevin   1547894567     CL
```

The pattern `[^\d]+` will match anything that is not a digit and that is what is removed.

Comment: that helped me , can you suggest any page or tutorial for cleaning data in python for situations like this.

Comment: @danishxr I'm sorry... I really don't know of anything besides the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods